# Remove type from Spring JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I have a Spring batch admin interface that was extende with a Restcontroller. 
It has to get the information from a MongoDB database and return the values in JSON format. 
It does this but the output looks as follows:

```
[
    "java.util.ArrayList",
    [{
    "@class": "com.exmple.project.admin.System",
    "name": "status",
    "statusList": [
    "java.util.ArrayList",
    [{
        "@class": "com.exmple.project.admin.Status",
        "name": "Exported",
        "value": 5275
    },
    {
        "@class": "com.exmple.project.admin.Status",
        "name": "Imported",
        "value": 1
    }]
]}]
]
```

I don't want the @class tags and the java.util.arrayList however. 
This is the method that returns the output:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/systems", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers="Accept=application/json")
public List<System> getSystems() {  
    List<System> systemList = new ArrayList<>();
    System syst = new System();
    syst.setName("systemName");
    List<String> list = mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection").distinct("status");
    for (String system : list) {
        DBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
        dbo.put("status", system);
        syst.getStatusList().add(new Status(system, mongoTemplate.getCollection("collection").find(dbo).count()));
    }
    systemList.add(syst);
    return systemList;
}
```

I have found examples like:
http://www.java2blog.com/2015/09/spring-restful-web-services-json-example.html

I don't know if it's a dependency that i'm missing (i tried the jackson.core one) or something wrong with the method itself. 
I want a basic JSON output like they have but i can't figure out how.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try returning a simple pojo from the `getSystems` method. If that works, your json converter is working properly.